# Add network interface to vm in azure

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, azure

I have VM with windows server in Azure with dynamic IP. Now, I want add second network interface with static IP.

So, I created "public IP-address", created network interface and Associate IP and interface. But how add interface to VM?

Both interface in same virtual network.

Comment: Are you using a classic or resource manager VM?

Answer (score 2):

Unless things have changed recently, you can't add a 2nd NIC to a running VM. you can only add multiple NICs when the VM is Created. This is from the Azure documentation site:

•A VM with single NIC cannot be configured with multi NICs (and vice-versa) once it is deployed, without deleting and re-creating it

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-multiple-nics/

You could delete the VM, Saving the VHD and create a new VM with multiple NICs using the existing VHD.

Comment: That was the case with the classic model, it is not with the Resource Manager model

Comment: Hi Sam, do you have a link to documentation that details the change? I cant find any reference to adding an additional NIC to an existing VM Classic or Resource Manager other than the one in my post.

Comment: so it's not quite as clear as I had though. You can add NICs to an existing ARM VM through powershell, but only if the VM was created with 2+ NICS. You can't add to a single NIC machine. All the machines I have done this on had 2 NICS to start.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to add a NIC to an existing VM directly. Maybe we can try to redeploy the VM with two NICs. Here is my PowerShell script to redeploy the VM:
[image]

```
    $rg = "jason-newgroup"
    $loc = "japan east"
    $nic01 = "nic01"
    $nic02 = "nic02"
    $vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name ‘jason-newgroup-vnet’ -ResourceGroupName ‘jason-newgroup’
    $sub01id = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name ‘sub01’ -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id
    $sub02id = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name ‘sub02’ -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id
    $ip1 = '10.1.0.5'
    $ip2 = '10.1.1.5'
    $nic1 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nic01 -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $loc -SubnetId $sub01id -PrivateIpAddress $ip1
    $nic2 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nic02 -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $loc -SubnetId $sub02id -PrivateIpAddress $ip2
    $vmsize = "Standard_DS4_v2" 
    $vmname = "jason-windows" 
    $vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmname -VMSize $vmsize 
    $VM = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VM -Id $nic1.Id -Primary
    $VM = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VM -Id $nic2.Id
    $osDiskName = "jason-newtest" 
    $osDiskVhdUri = "https://jasonnewgroupdisks717.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jason-windows2016920165635.vhd" 
    $vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -VhdUri $osDiskVhdUri -name $osDiskName -CreateOption attach -windows
    New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $loc -VM $vm
```

[image]
Notice:

The VM size determines the number of NICS that you can create for a VM. More information about how many NICS each VM size supports, please refer to the link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/

Hope this helps you.
If you still have questions, welcome to post back here.

Best Regards,